# Can I program a sensor?

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out what senior project that I should do for my senior year in my school. I've an idea which is to program a sensor and link it to your smartphone via Bluetooth or WiFi, to do read the data from a sensor.

I'm not sure if this possible or not? I'm new to this, would anyone help me how to get a sensor and program it using Java to do certain job, such as read burning calories and so on..

Comment: This question is too broad for the format of this website. We usually can help with specific issues in the code that you present to us. This question has too many ways and opinions on how to do it. It requires a very complex answer that would not fit on this page.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the Raspberry Pi (http://www.raspberrypi.org/).

It is an affordable, common, prototyping board to which you can connect a bunch of sensors and programming it with Java.